# How to I count the number of zeros in string until i come across a non zero vb.net

Tags: vb.net, count

Examples

IF the user enters a 00001 the count would be 4

If the user enters a 0811 the count would be 1

How would i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way is to simply loop through the characters of the string and count each character that is a `0` until your read a non `0` character.

I do not use VB.NET much, so this is just some rough VBish pseudo code

```
Dim myString As String = "00001"
Dim count As Integer = 0
For Each c As Char In myString
  If C = "0"c Then
    count += 1
  Else
    Exit For
  End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

And here is the one line answer without a visible for loop.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine(GetLeadingZeros("00001"))
        Console.WriteLine(GetLeadingZeros("0889"))
        Console.WriteLine(GetLeadingZeros("1"))
        Console.WriteLine(GetLeadingZeros("00101"))
        Console.WriteLine(GetLeadingZeros("11111"))
        Console.WriteLine(GetLeadingZeros("10001"))
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Public Function GetLeadingZeros(ByVal input As String) As String
        Return input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf(input.SkipWhile(Function(e) e = "0")(0)))
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Is it for efficient than the other one (the loop one) I know how to solve it using for/while but I'm searching for efficient one.